# Split the session variable into an array using recreating individual session variables

Tags: coldfusion

The typical way government offices make you record mileage is to enter one number per input box like the example below:

[image: Example of mileage entry]

So what I am trying to do is create one input box that can split the session variable into an array. Then when that session variable is split into an array I would like it to set each value in the array to its own session variable.

Mileage Input:
 
123456 -`<cfoutput>#session.checkout.vehicle.mileage#</cfoutput>`

array [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
6 -`<cfoutput>#session.checkout.vehicle.mileage1#</cfoutput>` 
5 -`<cfoutput>#session.checkout.vehicle.mileage2#</cfoutput>` 
4 -`<cfoutput>#session.checkout.vehicle.mileage3#</cfoutput>` 
3 -`<cfoutput>#session.checkout.vehicle.mileage4#</cfoutput>` 
2 -`<cfoutput>#session.checkout.vehicle.mileage5#</cfoutput>` 
1 -`<cfoutput>#session.checkout.vehicle.mileage6#</cfoutput>`

So then I will be able to prefill in an already created form that has the boxes split for only one per box.

**Where I am super confused** and trying to comprehend is that there will not always be 6 variables. Let's say the mileage is `2344`. I am assuming it will need to know to start backwards, counting from the right to the left. That's why I started 6 at `#session.checkout.vehicle.mileage1#`

Hopefully I have not super confused anyone with what I am trying to do. And any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
<cfparam name="form.mileage" default="#session.checkout.vehicle.mileage#">
...
<label for="mileage">Mileage:</label>
<input type="text" name="mileage"
       id="mileage" 
       value="<cfoutput>#form.mileage#</cfoutput>">
```

**Edit:**

The issue I am having with this is let's say the mileage is 9000 all 0's will not show. (which is great for the first two zero's in (009000) but after the 9 those 0's would still need to show.) Do you any ideas for that issue? Or should this be a new question?

```
<cfset Mileage = "9000" />
<cfif mileage is not "Exempt">
  <cfset Mileage = NumberFormat(trim(Mileage),"000000") />
  <cfset MilArray = ReMatch("\d",Mileage) />
<cfelse>
  <cfset MilArray = ["E","x","e","m","p","t"]>
</cfif>
<cfdump var="#MilArray#">

<cfif MilArray[1] is not "0">
    <!---Section6 First box Odometer Reading---> 
    <cfpdfformparam name="E" value="#MilArray[1]#"> 
<cfelse>
    <cfpdfformparam name="E" value="">
</cfif>
```

Comment: It is possible you are over-complicating things.  Why do you think you need to create separate variables to prefill a set of form fields? What does javascript have to do with this?

Comment: Nothing you have described so far suggests you actually need to do that. You can separate the mileage value and populate the fields without creating individual session variables.  See Dan's example on how to extract characters from a string. Also, you still did not explain what javascript has to do with this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding, you want to divide the string into six easy to work with variables, or whatever the length of the variable is.

```
<cfset Mileage = "123456" />
<cfset MilArray = ReMatch("\d",Mileage) />
<cfdump var="#MilArray#" />
```

You can actually stick a `Reverse()` in there to reverse the string, this may be handy because you can have `[1]` at the ones place, `[2]` at tens, `[3]` at hundreds.

```
<cfset Mileage = "123456" />
<cfset MileageR = Reverse(Mileage) />
<cfset MilArray = ReMatch("\d",MileageR) />
<cfdump var="#MilArray#" />
```

`\d` by itself in regular expressions just means "one digit". It's the same as `[0-9]`.

As the CFDUMP will show, `ReMatch` will split your mileage into an easy to work with array. If you use the reverse as above, you can say "The last digit of your mileage is `#MilArray[1]#`.", as an example.

Edit:

> you know the \d ? is there a way to have it be either \d or only the word Exempt? is it possible to create both of those?

There are a few ways.

You can say

```
<cfif mileage is not "Exempt">
    ...
<cfelse>
  <cfset MilArray = ["Exempt"]>
</cfif>
```

which creates a one dimensional array populated with "Exempt" as the only element, which might be useful later in your code so you know MilArray is always an array, or you can simply always work with the `<cfif mileage is not "Exempt">`.

A regex to accomplish the same thing is possible but it achieves the same as the above cfif, and you'd have to write exempt backwards if you're using reverse, like this

```
<cfset MilArray = ReMatchNoCase("\d|^Exempt$|^tpmexE$)",trim(Mileage)) />
<cfif MilArray[1] is "tpmexE"><cfset milArray = ["Exempt"] /></cfif>
```

Edit #2:

> `<cfif isDefined("session") and structKeyExists(session, 'checkout') and structKeyExists(session.checkout, 'info') and structKeyExists(session.checkout.info, 'oreading')>
>       <cfif isDefined("#MilArray[6]#") eq "">
>         <cfpdfformparam name="E" value="">
>         <!---Section6 First box Odometer Reading--->
>       <cfelse>
>         <cfpdfformparam name="E" value="#MilArray[6]#">
>       </cfif>
>     </cfif>`

This is a task for `ArrayIsDefined()` ([link](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ArrayIsDefined))

```
  <cfif isDefined("session") and structKeyExists(session, 'checkout') and structKeyExists(session.checkout, 'info') and structKeyExists(session.checkout.info, 'oreading')>
    <cfset MilArray = ReMatch("\d",session.checkout.info.oreading) />
    <cfif not ArrayIsDefined(MilArray,6)>
      <cfpdfformparam name="E" value="">
      <!---Section6 First box Odometer Reading--->
    <cfelse>
      <cfpdfformparam name="E" value="#MilArray[6]#">
    </cfif>
    .... I assume that it continues on down from here... <cfif not ArrayIsDefined(MilArray,5)>........</cfif> 
  </cfif>
```

Finally, while there's contention here on whether to use `StructKeyExists()` over `IsDefined()`, there's a narrow field where `isDefined()` fails.

(Don't put structures in the top level and in the variables scope. Cold Fusion gets confused--IE, don't create an object called "`variables.form`" or "`variables.url`"). Beyond that, It's mostly just semantics.

Anyway. once you have the above code working (because it's your code and your familiar with it), you might find it useful to switch to the easier to read `IsDefined()` version, because isDefined can check several levels deep in one condition.

```
  <cfif isDefined("session.checkout.info.oreading')>
    <cfset MilArray = ReMatch("\d",session.checkout.info.oreading) />
    <cfif not ArrayIsDefined(MilArray,6)>
      <cfpdfformparam name="E" value="">
      <!---Section6 First box Odometer Reading--->
    <cfelse>
      <cfpdfformparam name="E" value="#MilArray[6]#">
    </cfif>
  </cfif>
```

Edit 3:

Leigh points out

> Why so complicated? Can't you just left pad the value with spaces or zeroes? Then change the regex to check for either a digit or space? Then the array will always have six elements

This can be achieved like this:

```
<cfset Mileage = "exempt" />
<cfif mileage is not "Exempt">
  <cfset Mileage = NumberFormat(trim(Mileage),"000000") />
  <cfset MilArray = ReMatch("\d",Mileage) />
<cfelse>
  <cfset MilArray = ["E","x","e","m","p","t"]>
</cfif>
<cfdump var="#MilArray#">
```

Which would conveniently drop Exempt into place (handy that it's 6 characters).

You need to do some prechecking before you start generating the pdf to make sure that mileage variable is Exempt or or numeric.

```
<cfif len((trim(mileage)) gt 6 or not ((isNumeric(trim(mileage))
      or mileage is "exempt")>
  <!--- The 6 above is a len-check, you may need to update that number to 
        something else later, but you'll have to put the same number of 0s
        in the NumberFormat function.

        If you change that number, and the 0s, you'll need to pad the 
        "Exempt array"... ie ["E","x","e","m","p","t"," "] --->
  ....raise a flag...
</cfif>
```

Comment: Why so complicated? Can't you just left pad the value with spaces or zeroes? Then change the regex to check for either a digit or space? Then the array will always have six elements.

Comment: That's a good point though Leigh, appended to my answer to demonstrate how it can easily be done.

Comment: I just wanted to go ahead and say thank you guys so much!! I really appreciate your help its really amazing the knowledge you guys have!

Comment: @Leigh with the example you posted above I am having an issue and was wondering if you know a work around

Comment: *all 0's will not show* Take a look at your CFIF code. That is exactly what you are instructing CF to do. If that is not the result you want - change the CFIF.

Comment: With the code I gave you, the cfif should not be necessary. the array elements will either by numeric or one of (E,x,e,m,p,t) in proper order. @vicki

Comment: If you do not want the e x e m p t to show, change the cfif to simply `<cfif isnumeric(trim(mileage_variable))>`

Comment: @cfqueryparam well I still want the exempt but the issue I am having is I wanted to only remove the 0's infront of the number so 009000 would read 9000 and 900000 would still read 900000 and 000090 would read 90 the problem is that it also removes the 0 once the number has started

Comment: @Leigh ^^ I know that's how I wrote the cfif's but im not sure of another way I can do that? You think ill probably just have to keep those 0's infront of the number also or something?

Comment: @vicki Change the numberformat's `000000` to `999999` and then remove that cfif. Leading 0s will be turned to spaces.

Comment: RE: *Change the numberformat's...* @cfqueryparam - That would not produce the leading spaces. Instead try something like `RJustify(Mileage, 6)`. Then change the regex to `ReMatch("[\s\d]",Mileage)`

Comment: @Leigh your right like always :) that fixed it!!! Thanks a bunch you genius you!!! :)

Comment: @Leigh what does the \s do?

Comment: @Leigh `999999` does work, but the regex has to be changed in the fashion as you described. Vicki, \s means single white space character like tab, carriage return, space. In this case it's getting the spaces.

Comment: @cfqueryparam - Ah, you are right. The regex was missing piece.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler way.

```
originalNumber = "123";
sixDigitNumber = right(("000000" & originalNumber), 6);

<cfoutput>
<cfloop from="1" to = "6" index="position">

do something useful with #Mid(sixDigitNumber, position, 1)# 
</cfloop>
<cfoutput>
```

Comment: Start by simply displaying each digit.  It will give you confidence.  In fact, if all you have to do is prepopulate 6 1 character text boxes, you don't necessarily need a loop.  Just hard code everything.

Comment: `session.checkout.vehicle.mileage1 = Mid(sixDigitNumber, 1, 1);`, `session.checkout.vehicle.mileage2 = Mid(sixDigitNumber, 2, 1);` etc. (as Dan said - if all you're doing is populating 6 textboxes, don't bother looping)

Comment: <script> encloses javascript.  <cfscript> encloses ColdFusion code.

Comment: As long as you have the original number, it's not clear why you need the extra session variables.